# Python append function is not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = []
>>> b.append(a)
>>> print(b)
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> num = a.pop(0)
>>> a.append(num)
>>> print(a)
[2, 3, 1]
>>> b.append(a)
>>> print(b)
[[2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]]
>>>
```

Why is this happening and how to fix it? I need the list like

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1]]
```

Thank you.

**Edit:**

Also, why is this working?

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b.append(a)
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b.append(a)
>>> print(b)
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> 
'''
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Comment: I think your edit works because you are re-assigning the variable `a` rather than modifying the existing value. This probably creates a 'new' version of `a` which exists independently of the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every variable name in Python should be thought of as a *reference* to a piece of data. In your first listing, `b` contains two references to the same underlying object that is also referenced by the name `a`. That object gets changed in-place by the operations you’re using to rotate its members. The effect of that change is seen when you look at *either* of the two references to the object found in `b`, or indeed when you look at the reference associated with the name `a`.

Their identicality can be seen by using the `id()` function: `id(a)`, `id(b[0])` and `id(b[1])` all return the same number, which is the unique identifier of the underlying list object that they all refer to. Or you can use the `is` operator: `b[0] is b[1]` evaluates to `True`.

By contrast, in the second listing, you *reassign* `a`—in other words, by using the assignment operator `=` you cause that name to become associated with a different object: in this case, a new `list` object that you just created with your square-bracketed literal expression. `b` still contains one reference to the old list, and now you append a new reference that points to this different piece of underlying data. So the two elements of `b` now look different from each other—and indeed they are different objects and accordingly have different `id()` numbers, only one of which is the same as the current `id(a)`.   `b[0] is b[1]` now evaluates to `False`

How to fix it? Reassign the name `a` before changing it:  for example, create a copy:

```
a = list(a)
```

or:

```
import copy
a = copy.copy(a)
```

(or you could even use `copy.deepcopy()`—study the difference).  Alternatively, rotate the members `a` using methods that entail reassignment rather than in-place changes—e.g.:

```
a = a[1:] + a[:1]
```

(NB *immutable* objects such as the `tuple` avoid this whole confusion —not because they behave fundamentally differently but because they lack methods that produce in-place changes and therefore force you to use reassignment strategies.)

Answer (score 2):

Append a copy of your list `a`, at least the first time. Otherwise, you've appended the same list both times.

```
b.append(a[:])
```

Answer (score 1):

When you append the list `a`, python creates a reference to that variable inside the list `b`. So when you edit the list `a`, it is reflected again in the list `b`. You need to create a copy of your variable and then append it to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making the copy of a by doing `a[:]` and assigning it to `b`.
You can also use [collections.deque.rotate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) to rotate your list

```
from collections import deque

a = [1,2,3]
#Make a deque of copy of a
b = deque(a[:])

#Rotate the deque
b.rotate(len(a)-1)

#Create the list and print it
print([a,list(b)])
#[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1]]
```